# Fetch value using AJAX in WordPress

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to fetch results using AJAX in WordPress.I put below code in `functions.php`.

```
function get_data()
{
    echo 'Ajax call output:';
    wp_die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data'); 


function team_scripts()
{
    wp_localize_script('team_script', 'team_ajax_url', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    
    wp_enqueue_script('Select2', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js', null, null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('Select2', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('team_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/team_style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('team_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/team_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'team_scripts');
```

I put below code in `team_script.js`

```
(function($) {  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function(event) {
      // Check if select is already loaded
      if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
        var cellEle = $(this);

        // Populate select element
        cellEle.html(`<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"></select>`);

        // Initialise select2
        let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            action : 'get_data', 
            processResults: function(data) {
              return {
                results: data
              };
            },
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

But this is not working. I am not getting any error in console also.

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab? Is your AJAX request being sent? What's the response? I notice you're using the AJAX functionality of select2, are you returning data in the format that select2 requires? Probably not if you're just printing some text. Are you using the AJAX functionality correctly? You seem to have added `action` to the settings for select2, but normally it would need to go inside data that is sent with the AJAX request. Have you checked how to do that with select2 (note that this has nothing to do with WordPress).

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. Here is the output of Network tab. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGsMH.png. I tried with this code also. `ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            action : 'get_data', 
            processResults: function(data) {
              console.log(data)
            },
          }`
But it is also not working.

Comment: A 400 error means your not passing the action field correctly. You’ll need to check the select2 documentation for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I searched a lot for the solution but I didn't get any solution so far. Thanks.